# Problem when reshaping data from long to wide format in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Checking a different thread, I learnt about the function reshape from the stats package, I had no problem using it on a 'dummy' dataset, and managed to convert it from a long to a wide dataset. However, I don't know why it is not working on my data, it is pretty much the same object, the data types are similar. I'd appreciate you guys help me figure out the reason its behaving like it is.

Anyway, this gives no trouble:

```r
> df <- data.frame(
  +     year   = c(rep(2000, 12), rep(2001, 12)),
  +     month  = rep(1:12, 2),
  +     values = rnorm(24)
  + )

# year    month    values
1  2000     1    1.52435428
2  2000     2   -0.89394797
3  2000     3    0.75965499
4  2000     4    1.21497443
```

Converted to wide:

```r
df_wide <- reshape(df, idvar="year", timevar="month", v.names="values", direction="wide")

# year    values_1  values_2  values_3  values_4   values_5    values_6   values_7 values_8  values_9  values_10 values_11  values_12
1  2000 1.524354 -0.893948  0.759655 1.2149744 -1.3237634 -0.08681768  0.5208436 -0.2602807 0.6378904 -0.9852600 -1.128048 -0.1466028
2  2001 1.913969 -1.966720 -0.947688 0.8375891 -0.1015944  1.11812723 -1.5164472 -0.7089485 0.5975851  0.2514546 -1.578210 -0.9044418
```

But when using my data, which looks like this:

```r
my_df <- dput(head(experiment, 30))

structure(list(transcript = c("TR100743-c0_g1_i3", "TR100743-c0_g1_i3", 
"TR100743-c0_g1_i3", "TR100743-c0_g1_i3", "TR100743-c0_g1_i3", 
"TR100987-c0_g1_i2", "TR100987-c0_g1_i2", "TR100987-c0_g1_i2", 
"TR100987-c0_g1_i2", "TR100987-c0_g1_i2", "TR101301-c4_g1_i16", 
"TR101301-c4_g1_i16", "TR101301-c4_g1_i16", "TR101301-c4_g1_i16", 
"TR101301-c4_g1_i16", "TR102190-c1_g1_i1", "TR102190-c1_g1_i1", 
"TR102190-c1_g1_i1", "TR102190-c1_g1_i1", "TR102190-c1_g1_i1", 
"TR102346-c0_g2_i1", "TR102346-c0_g2_i1", "TR102346-c0_g2_i1", 
"TR102346-c0_g2_i1", "TR102346-c0_g2_i1", "TR102352-c4_g2_i5", 
"TR102352-c4_g2_i5", "TR102352-c4_g2_i5", "TR102352-c4_g2_i5", 
"TR102352-c4_g2_i5"), hours = c(0, 2, 8, 24, 48, 0, 2, 8, 24, 
48, 0, 2, 8, 24, 48, 0, 2, 8, 24, 48, 0, 2, 8, 24, 48, 0, 2, 
8, 24, 48), exp.change = c(NA, -43.1958273184645, -61.3014008509066, 
964.925115099619, -52.7060728326392, NA, -46.2563848585369, 3.29396898799807, 
-99.9994681489801, 106710484.025972, NA, -29.6341333478577, 522.224859380388, 
40.4737694947169, -1.34388206141046, NA, -18.7670826937756, 5.49472822880452, 
55.1072690537026, 33.5824607349752, NA, -99.999962131178, 789697313.24393, 
18.6337471833012, 52.4442959208125, NA, -31.3334122297108, 9.64745757892995, 
28.48552519881, 70.5808772231999), response = c("Primary", "Primary", 
"Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", 
"Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", 
"Primary", "Tertiary", "Tertiary", "Tertiary", "Tertiary", "Tertiary", 
"Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", 
"Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))


# transcript        hours   exp.change response   
 1 TR100743-c0_g1_i3     0        NA    Primary 
 2 TR100743-c0_g1_i3     2       -43.2  Primary 
 3 TR100743-c0_g1_i3     8       -61.3  Primary 
 4 TR100743-c0_g1_i3    24       965.   Primary 
 5 TR100743-c0_g1_i3    48       -52.7  Primary 
 6 TR100987-c0_g1_i2     0        NA    Primary 
 7 TR100987-c0_g1_i2     2       -46.3  Primary 
 8 TR100987-c0_g1_i2     8         3.29 Primary 
 9 TR100987-c0_g1_i2    24      -100.0  Primary 
10 TR100987-c0_g1_i2    48 106710484.   Primary
```

Gives this when I attempt to 'reshape' it:

```r
my_df_wide <- reshape(my_df, idvar = c("transcript", "response"), timevar = "hours", v.names="exp.change", direction = "wide")

# transcript         response  `exp.change.c(0, 2, 8, 24, 48)`
 1 TR100743-c0_g1_i3  Primary                                NA
 2 TR100987-c0_g1_i2  Primary                                NA
 3 TR101301-c4_g1_i16 Primary                                NA
 4 TR102190-c1_g1_i1  Tertiary                               NA
 5 TR102346-c0_g2_i1  Primary                                NA
 6 TR102352-c4_g2_i5  Primary                                NA
 7 TR10396-c0_g1_i6   Primary                                NA
 8 TR11844-c0_g2_i1   Secondary                              NA
 9 TR12672-c1_g2_i1   Primary                                NA
10 TR12672-c1_g2_i2   Primary                                NA
```

Is it because of the NAs? I honestly don't know why it is behaving like that... any help is heavily appreciated.

Comment: How do you want your reshaped output to look like?
Something like this? `library(tidyverse);

my_df %>% spread(hours, exp.change, sep = "_")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reshaping data with `stats::reshape` can be tedious. Hadley Wickham and
his team have spent quite some time on creating a comprehensive solution.
First there was the `reshape2` package, then `tidyr` had `spread()` and `gather()`,
those are now <s>replaced</s> complemented by `pivot_wider()` and `pivot_longer()`.

This is how you can use `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to achieve the result, you seem to
be going for.

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(
  my_df,
  id_cols = c(transcript, response),
  names_from = hours,
  values_from = exp.change,
  names_prefix = "exp.change_"
)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   transcript response exp.change_0 exp.change_2 exp.change_8 exp.change_24
#>   <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 TR100743-… Primary            NA        -43.2       -61.3          965. 
#> 2 TR100987-… Primary            NA        -46.3         3.29        -100. 
#> 3 TR101301-… Primary            NA        -29.6       522.            40.5
#> 4 TR102190-… Tertiary           NA        -18.8         5.49          55.1
#> 5 TR102346-… Primary            NA       -100.  789697313.            18.6
#> 6 TR102352-… Primary            NA        -31.3         9.65          28.5
#> # … with 1 more variable: exp.change_48 <dbl>
```

I think having dedicated commands with dedicated documentation for the two transformations (wide/long) makes the `tidyr` commands much easier to use, compared to `stats::reshape()`.

EDIT:
`stats::reshape()` is giving weird results, because it seems to be having issues dealing with my_df being a `tibble`. Other than that your command was just fine. Just add in a `as.data.frame()` and you are good to go.

```r
reshape(
  as.data.frame(my_df),
  idvar = c("transcript", "response"),
  timevar   = "hours",
  v.names = "exp.change",
  direction = "wide"
)
#>            transcript response exp.change.0 exp.change.2  exp.change.8
#> 1   TR100743-c0_g1_i3  Primary           NA    -43.19583 -6.130140e+01
#> 6   TR100987-c0_g1_i2  Primary           NA    -46.25638  3.293969e+00
#> 11 TR101301-c4_g1_i16  Primary           NA    -29.63413  5.222249e+02
#> 16  TR102190-c1_g1_i1 Tertiary           NA    -18.76708  5.494728e+00
#> 21  TR102346-c0_g2_i1  Primary           NA    -99.99996  7.896973e+08
#> 26  TR102352-c4_g2_i5  Primary           NA    -31.33341  9.647458e+00
#>    exp.change.24 exp.change.48
#> 1      964.92512 -5.270607e+01
#> 6      -99.99947  1.067105e+08
#> 11      40.47377 -1.343882e+00
#> 16      55.10727  3.358246e+01
#> 21      18.63375  5.244430e+01
#> 26      28.48553  7.058088e+01
```

But since it seems that you are already using the tidyverse `tidyr::pivot_wider()` seems like the best fit.

Comment: You can also add `names_sep = "_"` inside `pivot_wider` to get more informative column names, similar to the `reshape` approach.

Comment: Good point! `names_sep = "_"` on its own doesn't do the trick here though. `names_prefix = "exp.change_"` seems to do what you are suggesting. Thanks for bringing it up, editing this in now.

Comment: Yup, it seems like I had to convert my tibble into a dataframe, and that's it! that made it work... and yeah, I'll try to move  to tidyverse functions only from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Using `stats::reshape`

```
# `idvar` has 1 value here 
reshape(my_df, idvar="transcript", timevar="hours", v.names="exp.change", direction="wide")

      transcript response exp.change.0 exp.change.2  exp.change.8 exp.change.24 exp.change.48
 1   TR100743-c0_g1_i3  Primary           NA    -43.19583 -6.130140e+01     964.92512 -5.270607e+01
 6   TR100987-c0_g1_i2  Primary           NA    -46.25638  3.293969e+00     -99.99947  1.067105e+08
11 TR101301-c4_g1_i16  Primary           NA    -29.63413  5.222249e+02      40.47377 -1.343882e+00
16  TR102190-c1_g1_i1 Tertiary           NA    -18.76708  5.494728e+00      55.10727  3.358246e+01
21  TR102346-c0_g2_i1  Primary           NA    -99.99996  7.896973e+08      18.63375  5.244430e+01
26  TR102352-c4_g2_i5  Primary           NA    -31.33341  9.647458e+00      28.48553  7.058088e+01
```

Using `data.table`

```
setDT(my_df)
dcast(my_df,transcript~hours, value.var="exp.change")

           transcript  0         2             8        24            48
 1:  TR100743-c0_g1_i3 NA -43.19583 -6.130140e+01 964.92512 -5.270607e+01
 2:  TR100987-c0_g1_i2 NA -46.25638  3.293969e+00 -99.99947  1.067105e+08
 3: TR101301-c4_g1_i16 NA -29.63413  5.222249e+02  40.47377 -1.343882e+00
 4:  TR102190-c1_g1_i1 NA -18.76708  5.494728e+00  55.10727  3.358246e+01
 5:  TR102346-c0_g2_i1 NA -99.99996  7.896973e+08  18.63375  5.244430e+01
 6:  TR102352-c4_g2_i5 NA -31.33341  9.647458e+00  28.48553  7.058088e+01

 dcast(my_df,transcript + response ~hours, value.var="exp.change")

           transcript response  0         2             8        24            48
1:  TR100743-c0_g1_i3  Primary NA -43.19583 -6.130140e+01 964.92512 -5.270607e+01
2:  TR100987-c0_g1_i2  Primary NA -46.25638  3.293969e+00 -99.99947  1.067105e+08
3: TR101301-c4_g1_i16  Primary NA -29.63413  5.222249e+02  40.47377 -1.343882e+00
4:  TR102190-c1_g1_i1 Tertiary NA -18.76708  5.494728e+00  55.10727  3.358246e+01
5:  TR102346-c0_g2_i1  Primary NA -99.99996  7.896973e+08  18.63375  5.244430e+01
6:  TR102352-c4_g2_i5  Primary NA -31.33341  9.647458e+00  28.48553  7.058088e+01
```

You can also use the old `reshape2` package

```
 reshape2::dcast(my_df,transcript + response ~hours, value.var="exp.change")

          transcript response  0         2             8        24            48
1  TR100743-c0_g1_i3  Primary NA -43.19583 -6.130140e+01 964.92512 -5.270607e+01
2  TR100987-c0_g1_i2  Primary NA -46.25638  3.293969e+00 -99.99947  1.067105e+08
3 TR101301-c4_g1_i16  Primary NA -29.63413  5.222249e+02  40.47377 -1.343882e+00
4  TR102190-c1_g1_i1 Tertiary NA -18.76708  5.494728e+00  55.10727  3.358246e+01
5  TR102346-c0_g2_i1  Primary NA -99.99996  7.896973e+08  18.63375  5.244430e+01
6  TR102352-c4_g2_i5  Primary NA -31.33341  9.647458e+00  28.48553  7.058088e+01
```