# How to consolidate observations in a data frame based on values in one column and and spread variables to new columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have  a dataframe:

```
v1 <- c("Bob", "Bob", "Fred", "Fred")
v2 <- c("Age", "KG", "Age", "KG")
v3 <- c(25, 80, 30, 90)
df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
df
    v1  v2 v3
1  Bob Age 25
2  Bob  KG 80
3 Fred Age 30
4 Fred  KG 90
```

I would like to consolidate the data so the table looks like this:

```
  V1   Age   KG
1 Bob  25    80
2 Fred 30    90
```

I have tried a variety of `tidyr` and `dplyr` functions without success.

Comment: `df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = v1, names_from = v2, values_from = v3)` for the `tidyverse` method.

Comment: I was wrong in describing my data. My data object is actually a `tibble` rather than a data.frame.  When you run this on a tibble you get the v1 names correctly, then a single concatenated column named ``v3.c("Pop", "Pop_25")`` and NA for the values.

Comment: The above works on dfs and tibbles. There is something else going on with your data that is not reproduced in your sample dataset e.g. no there's no Pop variable in your sample. This is why a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) is important when asking a question. If you don't find a solution in the link your question duplicated, update your question with the results of a `dput()`. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I just found another question with the same data frame vs tibble issue. The `pivot_wider`  solution works great. I had been using `reshape` before which was causing the trouble. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080483/problem-when-reshaping-data-from-long-to-wide-format-in-r